# Doxygen Search and Replace Output

Tags: doxygen, ironpython

I am working on generating a compiled help file (CHM) for using a C#-based API from IronPython.

In the output I have the type "Ironpython.Runtime.List" which won't make any sense to the Python users. I would like to change this to "PythonList" or something else.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Note - I am using doxygen 1.8.14 on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please add a small example in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... well I solved it with the following batch file.

```
set hhc=C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe

doxygen "%cd%\Doxyfile.cfg"

"%cd%\fnr.exe" --cl --find "IronPython.Runtime.List" --replace "List []" --dir "%cd%\html" --fileMask "*.html" --includeSubDirectories

"%hhc%" "%cd%\html\index.hhp"
```

fnr.exe is available from: http://http://findandreplace.io